# Import class PowerShell5 module

Tags: windows, powershell

I've created some classes, which I would like to split into several files. Unfortunately, the inheritance does not work. My only working solution is:

```
Using Module "<Path>"
```

That is not flexible and a nightmare for adjustments. 
My test folder structure looks like this:

```
Project
|
+-- classes
|   |
|   +-- domain
|   |   |
|   |   +---Domain.psm1
|   |
|   +-- dns
|       |
|       +--DNS.psm1
|
|
+-- functions
    |
    +-- test
        | 
        +-- test.ps1
```

My current approach including classes is mentioned here:
https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-classes/import-powershell-classes-from-modules

Domain.psm1:

```
class Domain
{
[string] fullname () {
    return "test.local";
}

static [Domain] $instance

static [Domain] GetInstance() {

    if ($null -eq [Domain]::instance) {

        [Domain]::instance = [Domain]::new()
    }

    return [Domain]::instance
}
}
```

DNS.psm1:

```
# Working:
#using module "C:\Users\test\Desktop\Project\classes\domain\Domain.psm1"

# Not working:
$scriptDir = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath ..\.. -Resolve
$classFile = -join($scriptDir, "\classes\domain\Domain.psm1")

$scriptBody = "using module $classFile"
$script = [ScriptBlock]::Create($scriptBody)
. $script

class DNS : Domain
{

    [int] testRecord() {

        return 9000;
    }

    # Init Singleton
    static [DNS] $instance

    static [DNS] GetInstance() {

        if ($null -eq [DNS]::instance)
        {
            [DNS]::instance = [DNS]::new()
        }

        return [DNS]::instance
    }
}
```

test.ps1:

```
$scriptDir = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath ..\.. -Resolve
$classFile = -join($scriptDir, "\classes\dns\DNS.psm1")

# Working: 
# Include DNS.psm1
$scriptBody = "using module $classFile"
$script = [ScriptBlock]::Create($scriptBody)
. $script

$task = [DNS]::GetInstance()
$task.testRecord()
$task.fullname()
```

In my test.ps1 I create an instance of the DNS class which extends the Domain class. Extending Domain fails with:

```
+     . $script
+     ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (C:\Users\test...\dns\DNS.psm1:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Is there an easy way to get this working ?

Comment: Why don't you encapsulate your classes in modules?  Then preface your scripts where they're needed with `using` directives?  This really is the *best* way to handle classes.  (they're mostly a novelty in my professional experience because you might as well be writing C# classes)

Comment: Thanks for the note ! If it's possible to export classes via modules it makes the procedure much easier. I'll try it later and let you know.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Like you said it's much easier to create modules and include them with `using`. Thanks for your help.